# Installing R on EC2 - Keys

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I try to install R on a EC2 instance (Ubuntu) and there are some helpful pages explaining how to do it. In this line:

```
sudo apt-key adv —keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com —recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

My doubt is the E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 key, is it a public key? Should I generate one myself or does it belong to R?

Please, your kind answers and guidance will be appreciated.

Regards,

Alexis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a key used to sign the Ubuntu archives for R. Use it as given. More details are at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html.

Comment: Thank you @BigFinger for your answer